# CF-ORM How to map these fields/tables

Tags: orm, coldfusion, one-to-many, many-to-one, table-relationships

I have 2 tables.

1. tb_Employees
2. tb_Orders

**tb_Employees** has the following fields

1. **empID**
2. **name**

**tb_Orders** has the following fields

1. **orderID**
2. **clientName**
3. **empAccepted** (reference tb_Employees)
4. **empApproved** (reference tb_Employees)

When I pull the data;

- "**empAccepted**" works fine.
- "**empApproved**" shows data from empAccepted

**empApproved** is not showing its own data.

Does anyone know how to properly map this in CF ORM?

<----------------   Added   ---------------->

I have many fails.

I can post all of them - but, I think it's a waist of time.

**NONE OF THEM WORKED**

I want to learn how to properly map this scenario out.  **THE RIGHT WAY**.

I thought I gave enough, basic info for mapping.

***However, due to popular demand : )))))***

Which 'FAIL' should I post?

I'm posting 1 of my fails. (I have over 12 fails).

12 different files on ways NOT to do it. : )))

I have changed this so many times.  Took things out.  Added things.

I just want to know how to map this scenario correctly.

**tb_Orders.empApproved ... keeps showing data from ... tb_Orders.empAccepted**

**tb_Employees**

```
<!---- properties ---->
<cfproperty     name="empID"                    
        fieldtype="id" 
        setter="false" 
        column="empID_pk" 
        generator="native"  />

<cfproperty     name="name" 
        type="string"  />



<cfproperty     name="approved" 
        fieldtype="one-to-many" 
        cfc="tb_Orders" 
        fkcolumn="empApproved"  />

<cfproperty     name="accepted" 
        fieldtype="one-to-many" 
        cfc="tb_Orders" 
        fkColumn="empAccepted"  />
```

**tb_Orders**

```
<!---- properties ---->
<cfproperty     name="orderID"                      
        fieldtype="id" 
        setter="false" 
        column="orderID_pk" 
        generator="native"  />

<cfproperty     name="clientName" 
        type="string"  />


<cfproperty     name="empAccepted"  
        insert="false" 
        update="false" 
        fieldtype="many-to-one" 
        cfc="tb_Employees" 
        inverse="true"  />


<cfproperty     name="empApproved"  
        insert="false" 
        update="false" 
        fieldtype="many-to-one" 
        cfc="tb_Employees" 
        inverse="true"  />
```

Comment: It would help if you post your current mappings.

Comment: I'd like to know if anyone knows how to properly map this.

Comment: Its definitely possible. Can you post your code?

Comment: I would love to show my code - my mappings.
I made several versions.  NONE of them work right. I'm not sure which of the 'fails' I should show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a go.

```
<cfproperty name="empAccepted" type="tb_Employee"
        fieldtype="many-to-one"
        cfc="tb_Employee"
        fkcolumn="empAccepted"/>

<cfproperty name="empApproved" type="tb_Employee"
        fieldtype="many-to-one"
        cfc="tb_Employee"
        fkcolumn="empApproved"/>
```

Also, on **tb_Employees**, if you want that to control the relationship you'll probably want cascade and inverse there... like this

```
<cfproperty name="approved" type="Array"
    fieldtype="one-to-many"
    inverse="true"
    cfc="tb_Orders"
    fkcolumn="empApproved"
    singularname="tb_Order"
    cascade="all-delete-orphan"/>
```

Keep in mind, this is "Object" relational mapping, not "Relational Table" mapping. Its a good idea to get in the habit of thinking in "objects" and how they relate rather than your database.

Comment: ok - will give it a try - and post the results.  And ya - I'm still trying to think 'object'

Comment: Just on the "object" note, if your CFC is really named *"tb_Orders"*, you may consider renaming that to something like **Order**. Each **instance** of this CFC, represents a single order. Just think, you're describing an **Order**. The only thing that ORM does is *relate* that order to some database rules.

Comment: now - I only have one question.  How to I flag this question as 'Answered'?

Comment: thanks! <3 me some internet points. Just need to figure out how to cash them in.